# Swift - BLE Scanner response

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on a swift project where I scan and connect with peripheral device. I use the following code to write:

```
peripheral.writeValue(data as Data, for: characteristics[i], type: .withResponse)
```

but I want a response in hex. I also use

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    //characteristic.value has data
}
```

But I don't know how to get the response that I am asking for from .withResponse

Comment: What do you mean by "I want a response in hex?" `didWriteValueFor:` is just telling you that the value you wrote was successfully sent. "with response" has nothing to do with getting an answer; it just means "yes, the peripheral confirms it received our message." In BLE, it's possible write to the peripheral without getting any feedback about whether it was successful (that's "without response").

Comment: I am writing this to write a value var parameter = NSInteger(010303757372707764)
let data = NSData(bytes: &parameter, length: 18). But when I am writing a wrong value, I am not getting an error. Instead, if I get a hex response starting with 0F then its a success and if I get striating with 0E then its an error.

Comment: That `data` assignment is incorrect. You're taking an 8-byte value, and trying to read 16 bytes of memory. Your `data` is most random values found on the stack. What is  10,303,757,372,707,764? 10 quadrillion and change seems a really strange value to send a BLE device.